# ASP.NET Gridview: How do I stop a <span></span> within a Gridview from resetting when posting back?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, postback

I have a Gridview which contains some controls which are updated from the server when the user  makes a selection from a gridview.

After making their selection from a drop down list the user can enter a percentage into a textbox on a row and I have some javascript which then carries out some calculations and outputs to a span within an item template in the Gridview.

This all works but if the user then makes another drop down list selection on any row all the spans in the gridview are reset to blank (I've tried with various controls, both asp.net and html).

This is all inside an Update Panel.

Code:

```
 <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gdvIngredients" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-stripped"
                        GridLines="None" Visible="false" ShowFooter="true" EnableViewState="true">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblId" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ingredient" ItemStyle-Width="12%">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlName" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlName_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                        ForeColor="Black" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="%" ItemStyle-Width="6%">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text="0" Width="50px" ID="txtPercentage" onkeyup="calculate(this);"
                                        ForeColor="Black" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="kj" ItemStyle-Width="6%">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblKj" CssClass="Kj" Style="display: none;" />
                                    <span runat="server" id="spnKj" class="NewKj">0</span>
                                </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look if your dropdown list selection do any PostBack.

If it does, then span values disappear, becuase Span is not ASP.NET webcontrol. After pages is postback, asp.net webcontrol values are restored from ViewState. So, spans doesn't have ViewState and no values are restored.
You can try to change your  tag to

```
 <span runat="server" id="spanIDHere">SomeValue here</span>
```

***runat="server"*** makes span to be HtmlGenericControl and maintains its ViewState.

Span values would not be saved after postback if you update them using Javascript. You should call server-side function to update span values or try to use Hidden fields to store your values.

Comment: Changing the span to runat="server" still doesn't retain the value, I'd tried using a asp.net label to store the value in before but that does not work either.

Comment: I've added the Gridview code, is there anything else you want to see?

Comment: If you update your Span values using Javascript, then it is working only on client-side. These values would not be seen on server side after PostBack. You need to call some server-side function or try to use hidden fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "AutoPostBack" property to control the Postback event of some controls.

Comment: The postback needs to happen though, I just need to retain the values in the controls that get updated via javascript.

Comment: I think you can keep the control values in viewstate or sessions, then load it back while postback

Answer (score 0):

From your question what i have understood is that you are doing calculation in javascript and assigning it to span,but when next postback happens the value is not retained...If i am right i would suggest you to try the following steps.Use HiddenFields also to assign Values as HiddenFields Retain values during PostBacks.

1. Add Hidden field in Item Template
2. Set "calculate" function to Textbox from Codebehind(from rowdatabound event) & also pass the currosponding HiddenField Value to it as calculate(this,'HiddenFieldId');

   ```
   protected void grd_RowDataBound(object sender,GridViewRowEventArgs e)                   
    {              
             if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)        
              {            
                 HiddenField hdn = ((HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("HiddenFieldID"));   

                 TextBox txtPercentage = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtPercentage");

                  HtmlGenericControl spnKj=(HtmlGenericControl )e.Row.FindControl("spnKj");

                 txtPercentage.Attributes["onClick"]="calculate(this,'"+hdn .ClientID+"');"   

                 spnKj.innerHTML=hdn.Value;
              }

    }
   ```

   **Javascript:**

Assign Calculated Value to Hidden Field...

```
     function calculate(hdnID)
      {
         var CalcValue=//do your Calculation
         document.getElementByID(hdnID).Value=CalcValue;
      }
```

3.In the DropDown PostBack Event Bind the GridView Again.

The above code should take care of the Issue You are facing.

Comment: The problem is I'm not binding any data to the grid, I'm just populating some values on the selected index changed of the drop down list. So RowDataBound isn't being fired.

Comment: I see you are not binding GridView and you want to retain values,you could still assign value to HiddenField and the after postback in pageload assign back that HiddenField Value to Span...Use "GridViewRow"

GridViewRow selectRow = grd.Rows(index).
HtmlGenericControl spnKj=(HtmlGenericControl )selectRow.Cells[3].FindControl("spnKj"); 
spnKj.innerHTML=HiddenField Value;